# nesting plyr function, d_ply, writing to .pdf by category

Tags: r, loops, pdf, nested, plyr

I'd like to wrap a d_ply function which automates writing a few hundred figures to .pdfs within another d_ply function to group writing of the pdfs by another categorical variable.  The data frame looks like this:

```
site  category  code value
1      first    x     10
1      first    y     8
1      second   x      30
2      first    x     3
```

etc.

Fields types are site= numeric, category =char, code = char, value = numeric.

This code accomplishes what I want, but only writes 1 plot to each pdf, so the result is about 20 files, each containing 1 plot instead of a plot for each code associated with the category.  The rest of the plots flicker on the monitor. Then the pdf closes and the next opens.  Repeat.

```
d_ply(df,"category",function(x){
pdf(file=paste(unique(x$category),".pdf"))
    d_ply( df, "code", function(y) {
    plot(data=y, value~site, xlab=names(df[1]),ylab=unique(y$code))
dev.off()
})    

})
```

This code writes all plots to each category, so the result is about 20 files, each containing all 300 of the plots.

```
d_ply(df,"category",function(x){
pdf(file=paste(unique(x$category),".pdf"))
    d_ply( df, "code", function(y) {
    plot(data=y, value~site, xlab=names(df[1]),ylab=unique(y$code))

})    
dev.off()
})
```

I appreciate the comments.

Update:  I resolved the issue above so passing on the solution.  This code block works, assuming a df and relevant field ids in the df exist.  The code reads record blocks in the df, grouping them by a categorical variable, plots a numeric field by category, then repeats for reach category, then closes the pdf. The other statements just describe the file, modify the field headers, and report the runtime.

```
all<-as.data.frame(read.csv(filename.csv', header=TRUE))                                      
is.data.frame(all)
   dim(all)    
   head(all)
   names(all)<-tolower(names(all))
   names(all)
count(all,"parametername")
ptm<-proc.time()
pdf(file="export.pdf")  
d_ply(all,"name",function(x) {
   plot(data=x,value~dce.id, xlab=names(all[1]), ylab=unique(x$name))
   })
dev.off()  
proc.time() -ptm
```

Comment: And you would like 20 files (one for each category), each containing all the plots of the corresponding codes?

Comment: I solved this, see update above.